# In pytest-html, is there a way to combine html reports of 2 different pytest runs?

Tags: pytest, pytest-html, pytest-xdist

Basically i have scenario where i need to run set of parallel pytests and another set of serial pytests separately.
Each will generate separate pytest-html reports.
But i am looking for solution to combine both the reports generated.
Eg:
py.test -n auto -m "not serial" --dist=loadfile --html=report1.html
py.test -n auto -m "serial" --dist=loadfile --html=report2.html

Is there a way to combine report1.html and report2.html and generate single html report ?

Comment: No, there is no combining of HTML reports. You have to implement that yourself.

Comment: As @hoefling said, it's not possible and there's a bug report on GitHub tracking it. https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-html/issues/183

Though people have use a workaround:

* Use pytest's junit feature to write junit/xunit/xunit2 reports.

* Combin the unit-reports with junitparser.

* Generate HTML reports with junit2html.

Comment: There is a new utility that does just that. I used it and it worked well for me.

https://github.com/akavbathen/pytest_html_merger

Answer (score 1):

## Pytest HTML Merger

There is a new utility that is able to merge multiple `pytest-html` reports.

I have used it in my workplace and it worked great for us.

Assume you have multiple html reports under current directory `./`.

### Installation

`pip install pytest-html-merger`

### Usage

`pytest_html_merger -i ./ -o ./merged.html`

Will generate a unified `pytest-html` report.

Tested on Linux but should work on Windows as well.

#### Link to github page

https://github.com/akavbathen/pytest_html_merger

Enjoy!